# why doesnt key authentication work for openssh?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

I am working on setting up a hadoop cluster, as per the following tutorial: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#sun-java-6

My problem comes in when I attempt to set up the ssh keys.  I follow the tutorial by generating a key using ssh-keygen, then I copy the key to authorized_keys.  I have tried copying the key using cat, as is suggested, and also using

```
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
```

and

```
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub localhost
```

None of these attempts works.  I always get the following output:

```
$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_5.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0a-fips 1 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
debug2: bits set: 482/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host localhost filename /home/hadoop/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host localhost filename /home/hadoop/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hadoop/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 523/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fe53c972650)
debug2: key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 127.0.0.1.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp 99:fb:15:b2:2f:44:3f:bc:9a:b4:fe:a8:9b:61:c7:b0:23:c5:4c:0d
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

This has brought my project to a screeching halt.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $SSH_AUTH_SOCK set to? Does `ssh-add -l` list your key? Does `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` fix the problem?

Comment: Try also checking permissions to your `~/.ssh/*`. It quite often causes similar troubles.

Comment: @aland: The server accepted the key, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @grawity

$SSH_SOCK_ADDRESS=/tmp/keyring-9X6hhc/ssh

>ssh-add -l
2048 c4:3a:3f:32:5c:f8:24:d8:22:ad:ba:e8:bb:43:35:3f hadoop@localhost.localdomain (RSA)

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
This only solved my problem temporarily.  after a  short while, connections began to fail again.

using ssh-copy-id, make sure you include the name of the user for which you are copying the id:

```
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your ssh-agent OK?

Try the following:

```
kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

Note that you must adjust ssh-add to the right user. I'm assuming it's the current one. If your generated keys are valid, this should put them on the authorized list and the server should stop asking for passwords. Just to mention, I've used the ssh+cat method only. The ssh-copy-id somehow messes auth files.